# Function parameter - pointer or reference to a pointer?

Tags: c++

```
void DeleteChildren(BSTNode *node)
{
    // Recurse left down the tree...
    if(node->HasLeftChild()) DeleteChildren(node->GetLeftChild());
    // Recurse right down the tree...
    if(node->HasRightChild()) DeleteChildren(node->GetRightChild());

    // Clean up the data at this node.
    node->ClearData(); // assume deletes internal data

    // Free memory used by the node itself.
    delete node;
}

// Call this from external code.
DeleteChildren(rootNode);
```

This function is deleting BST recursively.

I got a question about the first line, `BSTNode *node` ,
should I modify it to be `BSTNode *& node` ?

Comment: Are you having problems with the code that makes you think there's something wrong? It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, pointers are passed by value, so you're in essence "copying" the pointer when you pass it as a parameter.    Only pass by reference when you want the callee to modify the parameter in the caller.

Answer (score 3):

The only time you'd want to pass a pointer by reference is if you want to change what the pointer is pointing to. If you wanted to, say, set the nodes to `NULL` after deleting them, then you would need to pass as `BSTNode*&`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to. The pointer you give your DeleteChildren function will be deleted so rootNode will be deleted too.

Your parameter could be of type BSTNode *& if you need to modify the address stored rootNode. In this case you don't.

Answer (score 0):

No. Assuming  `rootNode` is also of `BSTNode*` type, both the `rootNode` and `node` point to the same memory location.